# How .NET define boundaries between threads that executes same code

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

When several threads are running the same piece of code, how CLR manages to keep them overstepping each other. Is it the AppDomain that manages these threads and define boundaries between different threads even though they might be acting on same code ( and possibly data)? If so how?

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple; for method variables (excluding captured variables, iterator blocks, etc), the variables are on the stack. Each thread has a different stack. This is no different to a recursive method on a single thread - the method variables are separate and independent per call.

For objects on the heap... ***it doesn't!!***. No boundaries; no protection. If you don't correctly synchronize etc, you will corrupt your data.

In short, this is your job.

Comment: Are value types created on the heap? What about static methods?

Comment: @PedroC88 value-types can be on either the stack (as local variables (except "captured", iterator blocks, etc)) or on the heap (as class fields, or in an array or boxed copy, or "captured", iterator blocks, etc). Structs that are themselves a field on *another* struct live where-ever that outer struct lives. Re static methods: the *variables* are on the stack and independent per-call; any static fields are shared and you must protect them from threading issues.

Comment: @Marc: Does this mean each thread has its own address space? If so who manages  this space, is it application domain or the process itself?

Comment: @imak not in the least; each thread has it's own *stack*, but the heap and address-space is shared

Comment: @Marc: Sorry but I am confused. If the address-space is shared my brain is failing me underst how these threads could have separate copy of same code. May be either if you can elaborate bit more or just point to any link where its explained in bit more detail.

Comment: @imak they don't have separate copies. They have the same code, the same assemblies, the same everything. They have different values on each stack - is that what you mean?

Comment: @PedroC88 @imak it is always hardest from there, as we have no shared terms / points of references ;p If you can be very specific about what the uncertainty is, I'll try to clarify...

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for explaining this but if they have different values on each stack then what is the need for TLS using techniques like ThreadLocal<T> that provides thread local storage for static & instance variables

Comment: When used as a regular *method variable* - very little point. However, when used as a **field** (an object-level variable, or `static` variable), this is a *huge* difference; now each thread accesses different state. This also applies to the more obtuse method variables: captured variables, iterator block variables, etc; because these can escape from a method, they aren't actually on the stack (they couldn't possibly be). So a `ThreadLocal<T>` local variable might make sense if that variable is "captured" as part of a lambda/anon-method used in a callback, or for use with `Parallel` etc.

Comment: The stack contains addresses.  A function is called, it must return to the caller.  That return point corresponds to an address.  Because a function can call yet another function which in turn needs an address to transfer control back to, you have a stack of these addresses.  Each thread has it's own copy.  This is how threads can share the same code - each has it's own record (stack) of addresses that define where it is currently and where it returns to when the current function completes.  The stack may also contain variables but it is the address concept that applies to execution.

Comment: @Sisyphus nicely put; which also ties back into how 2 threads executing a method is no different to a single thread calling the same method recursively / re-entrantly.

Answer (score 2):

It is an operating system implementation detail.  Windows maintains the processor context for each thread.  That context contains a copy of the state of the processor registers.  Really important ones that matter to your question is EIP, the Instruction Pointer, and ESP, the Stack Pointer.  The instruction pointer keeps track of the machine code instructions that are executed by the thread.  The stack pointer keeps track of the activation frame of the currently executing method.  Every thread has its own stack.

Since each thread has its own instruction pointer, they can each execute their own code, independent of other threads.  Having their own stack ensures that threads cannot stomp each others local variables.  Your machine has hundreds of threads running at the same time.  They take turns executing code for a while on an available CPU core.  It's the operating system's job to make that work, it saves the processor state in the thread context whenever it has been running for a while, or blocks, and it is time for another thread to get a turn.  Resuming that thread simply involves copying the state back from the saved context to the processor.  And it continues where it left off when it was interrupted.

Threading gets tricky once threads start to access memory that's shared by all threads.  In a .NET program, that's anything that's stored on the garbage collected heap as well as any static variables.  Having one thread that writes such memory and other threads reading the same memory needs to be orchestrated.  The *lock* keyword is one of the primary ways to do this.

The relevance of an AppDomain is that each one has its own garbage collected heap and 'loader heap' (the place where static variable values are stored).  Which prevents threads from stomping on each other completely.  It is quite equivalent to a process, without the associated operating system cost of a process.  Which is quite high on Windows.  AppDomains are important on custom CLR hosts, like ASP.NET and SQL Server.  They help isolating client requests so that, say, one web page request that bombs with an unhandled exception cannot also corrupt the state of all other requests.